# iOS MapKit show nearest annotations within certain distance

Tags: ios5, mapkit, xcode4.3, mkannotation

Currently i am working on a Location based application for iPhone/iPad . I have several annotations in my MapKit , what i want to do is to track the location of the user and shows the annotations that are within the 3km . Can somebody give me a start ?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Tracking location? Finding points within a radius? Displaying the annotations?

Comment: Displaying the annotations form the database and displaying points within a radius . Please suggest me some good tutorials if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response... the question just fell off my radar.

I'm going to suppose that you have a method that returns a set of NSValue-wrapped `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs (the basic approach is the same regardless of what your internal data representations are).  You can then filter the list using a method something akin to the following (warning: typed in browser):

```
NSSet *locations = ...;
CLLocation centerLocation = ...; // Reference location for comparison, maybe from CLLocationManager
CLLocationDistance radius = 3000.; // Radius in meters
NSSet *nearbyLocations = [locations objectsPassingTest:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D testCoordinate;
        [obj getValue:&testCoordinate];
        CLLocation *testLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:testCoordinate.latitude
                                                              longitude:testCoordinate.longitude];
        BOOL returnValue = ([centerLocation distanceFromLocation:testLocation] <= radius);
        [testLocation release];
        return returnValue;
    }
];
```

With the filtered set of coordinates in hand, you can create `MKAnnotation` instances and add them to the map in the usual manner, as described in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html).

If you have many thousands of test locations then I suppose this approach could start to incur performance issues.  You would then want to switch your point storage approach to use, e.g., [quadtrees](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves), to reduce the number of points that need to be precision-filtered.  But don't optimize prematurely!

Hope that helps!