# Show only annotations within x distance from User

Tags: json, xcode, mapkit, distance

I hope someone can help we, on how to proceed to implement this. I am a very beginner in xcode and programming. I am working on an application that shows the closest locations ( stores ) to the userlocation.
my app is in Xcode, and my locations are coded in a Mysql database, so what I am doing is, showing a map and through JSON parson the locations into the map.
I draw an circle overlay of 10 km.

What I want to do, is only show the annotations that are 10 km from the user, what is the smartest way to do it ?

I already read the answer in :
[iOS MapKit show nearest annotations within certain distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866297/ios-mapkit-show-nearest-annotations-within-certain-distance)

But I am not sure how to implement it ! ... is it smarter to do that while handling the JSON by the php in the server, or use the CLLocationDistance function in xcode, wich methode will use less memory/time resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is expected to make lots of changes to that circle or move about lots after they get the data, or if you can send all the search results to the device easily, then do the filtering locally.
If the result set (before filtering) is too large to send to the device then filter on the server and send back just what needs to be displayed.