# (Swift) set a 1km radius within my location MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm working on an App where I get the user location and some custom pins (Restaurants) that I added. What I want to do is set radius (between 5km and 10km) distance between the user and the restaurants and then show those that are within the area.

My question is, how can I set that radius and get the locations within it

Best regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS MapKit show nearest annotations within certain distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866297/ios-mapkit-show-nearest-annotations-within-certain-distance)

Comment: That question is in Objective-C, not Swift. So it doesn't qualify as a duplicate. @KeghamK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some distance calculations to determine what pins to show.

```
let pins = Array<MKPointAnnotation>() // This is an empty array, so just use your array of locations or add to this.

if let currentLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {

    for pin in pins {

        let locationMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(currentLocation)

        let pinMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(pin.coordinate)

        let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(locationMapPoint, pinMapPoint)

        if distance >= 5000 && distance <= 10000 {

            self.map.addAnnotation(pin)
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted something tidier, you could also do this.

```
let pins = Array<MKPointAnnotation>()

if let currentLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {

    let filtered = pins.filter { $0.coordinate.distance(to: currentLocation) >= 5000 && $0.coordinate.distance(to: currentLocation) <= 10000 }

    self.map.addAnnotations(filtered)
}
```

You'll need this extension aswell.

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    func distance(to coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {

        return MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPointForCoordinate(self), MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate))
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your answer, the code is clear and easy to follow; I will try it and let you know what happens.